# Invalid CSS property value for background with image and extension gradient

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

Chrome has started to warn me about my legacy gradients:

```
Invalid CSS property value: right no-repeat url('../Images/Logo_white.png'), 
-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #899fa6, #3e545c)
```

It is only for the extensions for o, moz and ms:

```
background: right no-repeat url('../Images/CompanyLogo.png'), 
-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #ffffff);
```

The one for webkit is fine:

```
background: right no-repeat url('../Images/CompanyLogo.png'), 
-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #ffffff);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

The extension-gradients do not generate a warning when they are used alone as opposed to being combined with an image.

Comment: Chrome will warn about browser prefixes for other browsers because it cannot interpret those values. If you look at the page in FireFox, it should warn you about the `webkit` browser prefixes and not warn you about the `moz` prefix

Comment: So I should accept the warnings or file a complaint on Chrome?

Comment: Accept the warnings, that's what it's suppose to do

Comment: Is there something else I can address?

Comment: The last part. Why it only complains when I combine it with an image as in my example. Not for a background: -moz-linear-gradient alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this bug on Chrome Developer Tools:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=309982

Seems like they will temporarily disable CSS warnings because of too many false positives (including valid CSS for legacy browsers, if we are to go by the ticket author) until they have fixed it.

Chances are that these warnings are part of those false positives.
I will monitor the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're getting warnings from Chrome's dev tool is because the values are indeed invalid for Chrome. However, this should not alarm you because this is the way that it was designed.

In CSS, if something is defined incorrectly or not recognized by the browser then it is simply passed over, nothing is done and it only gives a warning not an error. This behavior is exactly what allows vendor prefixes to work. Take for example your own situation:

```
background: right no-repeat url('../Images/CompanyLogo.png'), 
-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #ffffff);

background: right no-repeat url('../Images/CompanyLogo.png'), 
-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #ffffff);

background: right no-repeat url('../Images/CompanyLogo.png'), 
linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #ffffff);
```

Chrome goes through each `background` property and sees which one it can interpret. It can't interpret the first gradient because it doesn't recognize `-moz-` like Firefox does. It *can* interpret the second one because it has a `-webkit-` prefix. It can *also* interpret the third background because Chrome supports un-prefixed CSS gradients.

Since more than one CSS attributes affect the same thing (`background`), the most recent one listed (the unprefixed version) will be used. A warning will display for the un-interpretted first `background`, but it will have no effect on the project.

Yes, **warnings should be looked at and analyzed, generally treated as errors**. With that being said, the case you bring up about browser prefixes is the correct way of doing it, so the warnings should be accepted. In a perfect world they would not show up at all, they'd understand that it is meant for another browser, but there is no reason to worry about it because it is indeed the correct way of doing it

But then again, this is all semi irrelevant because [all major browsers support CSS gradients unprefixed](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient).

Comment: The problem with these kind of warnings is that they might end up hiding actual problems if all programmers learn that warnings always can and should be ignored. For example, at work we try to use treat warnings as errors for C# code. I was setting out to clean all the warnings in the devtools console. But from your post I guess it is not possible while still supporting legacy browsers?

Regarding -moz-linear-gradient, have I missed something? It looks like it exists to me:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient
See bottom of page, /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */

Comment: Agreed, I treat most warnings as errors as well, as should everyone. With that being said, the warnings you bring up in particular should be acceptable because they are in order to develop cross-browser solutions. It's different than a language like C# because C# works the same no matter what program is running it (generally speaking). Web programmers have to learn which warnings are acceptable. And you could be correct in saying there was a `-moz-linear-gradient`, I was going off of the [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient) documentation

Comment: It's ok. On caniuse, if you click on Show all versions-link it will show older browser versions including Firefox-versions that use -moz.

Comment: @SopKillen Updated my answer to reflect our discussion

Comment: Updated my post. Not sure what to do about this answer. It was a good discussion but the wished-for answer to my post would have been a link to that bug report. Should I still accept?

Comment: @SopKillen You're free to post your own answer and mark it as correct with the link to the bug report. Generally speaking you'd upvote this answer because it's helpful but accept the one you post. Another option would be to have me include the link. Either option is acceptable